# Cannot connect to the MySQL

Tags: java, jdbc

Can't connect to the server means that code outputs nothing. I think, the problem is in getting connection (even if I change login or pass). By the way, jdbc-driver is loaded (I didn't install it separatelly, it was installed by default with MySQL). 'users' table is located in newly created database. Please give an idea what to do:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class DBConn {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;

        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/users";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "1111");
            statement = conn.createStatement();
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM users");
            while(resultSet.next()){
                System.out.println(resultSet.getInt("user_id") + ":" + resultSet.getString("usersName"));
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

            try {
                if (resultSet != null) resultSet.close();
                if (statement != null) statement.close();
                if (conn != null) conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what exception u get in stack trace ?

Comment: `localhost:3306` refers to a TCP socket, but mysql tends to rewrite TCP "localhost" into a unix-domain socket connection instead for efficience. If your driver/client setup is incorrect and looking for the socket in the wrong place, you'll be unable to connect. That or it really IS trying to connect via tcp and your server has been configured with skip-networking and/or not binding to localhost:3306.

Comment: You are attempting to connect to a database named `users` and querying a table named `users`. Is this intentional? If so, you might need to change the SQL query to `resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM users.users");`. Otherwise it might be a user permission issue from within MySql. In any case, next time show us any errors you are getting as it will help you get your answers quicker, and helps us get a better idea of what your issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps otherwise your code is fine:

1. Check the `mysql-connector-java-xxx` library in your project
2. Is your Database `users`, hope not change it accordingly in below
   line:

`String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/<put your Database Name>";`

Comment: Guys, sorry for a long reply - I have full day work and can try your suggestions only late evening when I have access to the laptop. My fault is that I try to connect not to database but table passing as parameter to Driver.getConnection(url) wrong url (means that 'users' is a table located in particular database 'snippet'). So, the solution is to ammend the url as "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/snippet" and statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM users"). Thanks for everyone!